# Failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am exploring android supported dagger lifecycle to inject dependency in Kotlin but they always fail to generate dagger dependency code. The error occurred with fail messages are below:

```
    public abstract interface MainComponent {
                    ^
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
   failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
```

Here it is attached of MainComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,AndroidInjectionModule::class,AppModule::class, NetworkModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class))
open interface MainComponent{

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): MainComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: ActifyApplication)
}
```

I tried different solution like kapt enable true in app level gradle but not fixed yet.Would please give some insight why this case always. Your help would highly appreciate.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I met this kind of question is actually a member variable don't correspond to the cause of such as me

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideBookService(): AppApi {
        return AppApi.instance
    }
}
```

Here's AppApi. Instance as the App. The instance

Comment: It is totally unclear whether you attempt to answer the question or come up with your own problem. Please reformulate.